# Firefox Flicker Bug

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, flicker

Is there any sort of workaround for the bug that makes firefox flicker when decreasing the size of the document?

[Click here for a demo](http://steve.thefuhry.com/firefoxFlicker.php)

[Click here for the demo in quirks mode (no DOCTYPE)](http://steve.thefuhry.com/firefoxFlicker.php?quirks)

I bet it could be fixed using javascript -- whenever the scrollbar shrinks, make sure to scroll the window up to prevent the flicker or something.. thoughts?

**Update**: the bug does not appear to be present (or at least not as severe) in quirks mode

Comment: Not quite sure how the question relates to the demo.  For me, the demo resizes an image.  There is no change in any window size.  Is there something I ought to do to replicate?

Comment: Your demo has JS errors in it...

Comment: er.. change in document size or something.. i meant when there is overflow on the page, so the scroll bar is usable. try making the window smaller if you have high vertical resolution or something maybe.

also, Firebug is not throwing any JS errors for me..

Comment: **the demo does not work in IE. No matter though, because this bug is not present in IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:
The problem is that the page scrolls as the image gets resized.

Solution one:
Include the [jQuery](http://jquery.com) library and [jQuery Scroll](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo) plugin.
Then scroll to the image by doing the following:

```
$.scrollTo("#image", "fast", function(){
  //resize image here
});
```

OR!

simply disable overflow for the container of the image/page temporarily:

```
$(body).css("overflow", "hidden");
//do resize
//on resize end (after it has finished):
$(body).css("overflow", "auto");
```

should solve your problem!

## EDIT:

> I bet it could be fixed using javascript -- whenever the scrollbar shrinks, make sure to scroll the window up to prevent the flicker or something.. thoughts?

Yes!

```
//before resizing
var scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){
  $.scrollTo("#image", "fast");
}, 1);
//do your resizing
//once resizing done
clearInterval(scrollInterval);
```

Comment: The scrollTo plugin ended up being the only real workaround for me. Somewhere else I saw a suggestion to do overflow:hidden, then change it back to auto, but that has never worked for me.. too bad, because that sounds like the best possible fix.. Thanks!

Comment: I went to your demo and in Firebug added overflow:hidden to the body tag. No flicker. That doesn't work for you?

Comment: Yes, overflow:hidden removes the flicker -- but unfortunately it also removes the overflow :-p